# Specific partition of a space.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and $X=A\cup B$ (here $\cup$ denotes a set theoretic union) with $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $A$ and $B$ are locally compact. Can we write $X$ as a coherent union of a finite number of topological subspaces?

Comment: What is a **coherent** union?

Comment: It means if $X=C\cup D$ is  coherent then $F$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $F\cap C$ is closed and $F\cap D$ is closed.

Comment: Without requiring something more on $A$ and $B$ this condition is satisfied by every compact subspace $X$: take a point and its complement. And the answer is trivial "yes" if we treat $X$ itself as a subspace of $X$ and "no" otherwise unless $X$ is disconnected.